# Python - can call same class twice(or more) in thread?

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-multithreading

I don't very understand the classes logic in python but cannot answer on web.
I have create a class to generate person info:

```
class person:  
    def fristnameGen(gender):
        ...
    def emailGen(firstname,surname): 
        ...
```

i create a bot to call it like this:

```
from person import *
class bots:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.person = person()
    def createDB(self):
        print(self.person.name)
        #do something...
```

finally i call it by a button with thread

```
from bots import *
import threading
class Panel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = tk.Tk()
        self.bot = bots()
        self.buildUI()

    def foo(self):
        self.bot.createDB(self.stringPhone.get())

    def threadTheAction(func, *args):
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args) 
        t.setDaemon(True) 
        t.start()

    def buildUI(self):
        Button = tk.Button(self.top, text ="Start", command = lambda :self.threadTheAction(self.foo))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'Panel' object is not callable
```

However, i call it directly, its work

```
        Button = tk.Button(self.top, text ="Start", command = lambda :self.foo())
```

How to fix the error?
...
2. Moreover,  i tried create `p1 = person()` and `p2= person()` and print it. Found `p1` and `p2` is a same person, i prefer each new a class have a new one. How to generate "new person" using classes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of confusion about Object Oriented Programming in Python. Some of your methods have `self` parameters and some do not, seemingly at random. That's the source of your current error.

The `threadTheAction` method in your `Panel` class is getting the `Panel` instance passed in as its first argument, but that's named `func` in the method (since you omitted `self`). The real function you're passing as an argument gets caught in the variable argument `*args`. When the thread tries unsuccessfully to call it, you get an exception. Adding `self` before `func` would fix the immediate problem:

```
def threadTheAction(self, func, *args):
```

I suspect if your code got further along, you'd run into other errors with other methods without `self` in their parameter lists. For instance, none of the methods you've shown in `person` are likely to work correctly.

As for your second question, you haven't shown enough of `person` to know what's happening, but you're probably doing instance variables wrong somehow. With no `self` parameter in the methods, that's almost inevitable (since you assign to `self.whatever` to set a `whatever` attribute on the current instance). If you need help squaring that away, I suggest you ask a separate question (Stack Overflow is best when each question is self-contained) and provide the full code for your `person` class.

Comment: Thank you Blckknght! For threadTheAction, it is a mistake, because i copy from another post on Stack Overflow, but forgot it method within my class, i not way to fix it  for three days! for the second question, i want to spend more time to fix it myself, if still not fix, i will ask it later. Thank you!